# How to access SceneDelegate from NSObject?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I declared a variable in sceneDelegate and want to access that variable from the NSObject. We can do that from UIView or UIViewController, but don't know how to do this in NSObject.

Is there a way to access this variable?

Comment: You have some code to share kn what does not work?

Comment: you could use static. But, I wouldn't recommend, as I wouldn't recommend accessing in some `NSObject`.

Comment: @Frankenstein can't use static.

Answer (score 2):

If you have only one scene in application it is possible to do with

```
if let delegate = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first?.delegate as? Your_SceneDelegate_Class {
    // ... access anything needed in delegate
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem. App supports multi-window, so this won't be useful.

Comment: @AchyutSagar, multiple windows or multiples scenes? because multiple windows can be assigned with one scene. Anyway then you just need to iterate `UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes` and find needed delegate, but if they have same class then your task is not solvable due to ambiguity.

Comment: yeah I mean multi scene. Is there a way to filter out scene which I need in connectedScene?

Comment: @AchyutSagar, and which you need? there are all scenes there, so you have condition of interested scene, then yes you can filter one from those.